# in runnable_avg_period+1, why should I add 1?

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduler

kernel/sched/fair.c

```
static inline void __update_task_entity_contrib(struct sched_entity *se)
{
u32 contrib;

/* avoid overflowing a 32-bit type w/ SCHED_LOAD_SCALE */
contrib = se->avg.runnable_avg_sum * scale_load_down(se->load.weight);
contrib /= (se->avg.runnable_avg_period + 1);
se->avg.load_avg_contrib = scale_load(contrib);
trace_sched_task_load_contrib(task_of(se), se->avg.load_avg_contrib);
contrib = se->avg.runnable_avg_sum * scale_load_down(NICE_0_LOAD);
contrib /= (se->avg.runnable_avg_period + 1);
.....
```

this code calculates the below equation.

```
                        runnable_avg_sum
load_avg_contrib =  -----------------------------  * weight
                      runnable_avg_period + 1
```

and:

```
                        runnable_avg_sum
load_avg_ratio =  -----------------------------  * NICE_0_LOAD
                      runnable_avg_period + 1
```

Why should we use `runnable_avg_period + 1` in this equation?
Why can't we just use `runnable_avg_period`?

Comment: Could you add a little more description about the problem you have?

Comment: ah, I'm just studying linux CFS scheduler and I just wonder this equation fator. why did the author use "runnable_avg_period+1" instead of "runnable_avg_period". that's my question....

Comment: To protect from division by zero.

Comment: @myaut I agree with your comment. Actually, I wanted to find any related document or article. But, this comment is enough for me.